# In angularjs ajax carousel slider not working

Tags: angularjs, ajax

When i am adding static array then **slider** is working.
When using as below:

```
 $scope.bestDeals = [{imagename: 'test', title: 'Best Deal 1' }, {imagename: 'test1', title: 'test' } ];
```

But problem is while i am getting data by using ajax like:

```
$http.get(baseurl + 'controller/getimagesData/').success(function(data)             
    {   
        $scope.bestDeals = data;  
    });
```

Its not working .
I have already tried another **slider** also but same problem i am facing..

Comment: Have you tried debugging the result returned by the REST call? Try doing something like `console.log(data);` and compare it with the hard-coded array example.

Comment: can you log how your data is being retrieved?                $http.get(baseurl + 'controller/getimagesData/').success(function(data)             
    {    
       console.log(data);
        $scope.bestDeals = data;  
    });

Comment: yes.. i have checked data came proper format ..

[{"title":"sachin tendulkar","imagename":"","email":null,"phone_no":null,"information":null},{"title":"B","imagename":"1455693816soft2.jpeg","email":"B","phone_no":"2","information":"B"}]

suppose i have added this array without ajax then slider also working fine..

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your working on Bootstrap CSS for carousel. Just read the API docs of [UI-Angular Bootstrap carousel control](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

I believe your success callback contains the meta data of the images uploaded. Make sure to check the log of the meta data and its absolute path.

Or try to use **ng-src** directive in your img tag or use **$sce** for contextual escaping.